# Вписать 8 блоков в сетку

Tags: html, css

Как расположить 8 блоков таким образом, чтобы средний был в 2 раза выше?

[image: макет]

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/121115/discussion-on-question-by-alexandr-beknazaryan--8---).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Пожалуйста, вот вам структура по Flex как на вашей картинке. С размерами, думаю, вы и самостоятельно сможете справиться.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
  width: 30%;
  max-width: 200px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.item {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 100%;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

.container:nth-child(2)>.item:nth-child(2) {
  padding-top: calc(200% + 16px);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Элементы идут в нетипичном для человека порядке,но в целом думаю для этого ТС попрёт!...)))

Comment: Паша, кстати, твой пример не работает на мобиле

Comment: @MaximLensky на 11 айфоне пашет)) на 4S не пашет, там надо с отступами поиграть.. или повернуть мобилу на 90град)))

Comment: @СергейВ. 11 то по новее...мой пример работает на 4s ?

Comment: @СергейВ. https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/XWNvpRZ - а вот так это будет на grid

Comment: @MaximLensky нет, на 4S не работает, если в портрете. При повороте в пейзаж все ок на любой мобиле. Там дело не в новизне, а в ширине экрана.

Comment: @СергейВ. там у меня всё автоматом - 100% и всё ...

Comment: С вложенностью как-то неинтересно... Хотя всё равно плюсик поставил.

Answer (score 5):

## Высота в px

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 248px;
  margin: -4px;
}

div {
  height: 72px;
  margin: 4px;
  border: 3px solid red;
}

.long {
  height: 152px;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div class="long">5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
</main>
```

## Высота по контейнеру

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body, main {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: -4px;
}

div {
  height: calc(33.33333% - 8px);
  margin: 4px;
  border: 3px solid red;
}

.long {
  height: calc(66.66667% - 8px);
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div class="long">5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 4):

Не сложный макет - вообще на grid это делается

Grid позволяет управлять макетов в двух осях - по Х и по Y

Flex же только или по Х или по Y

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.flex{
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  justify-content: center;
}

.item{
  width: 33%;
}

.box{
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 200px;
  background: red;
}

.box-1{
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 200px;
  background: red;
}

.box-2{
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background: red;
}

.box,.box-1,.box-2{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 4px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="box-1"></div>
    <div class="box-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

## Лучше использовать `grid`, а не `flex`.

```css
html, body, main {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 8px;
}

div {
  border: 3px solid red;
}

.long {
  grid-row: span 2;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div class="long">5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
</main>
```